# Div moves down instead of hiding

Tags: css, html

So i have two dives in a container which has overflow:hidden.

However, when I increase the width of first div, the second one moves down instead of cutting of in the right side. Here is a [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1631rrpn/)

Increase the width of first div to 500px to see it happen.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="first">FIRST</div>
<div id="second">SECOND</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because container width is 500px and the second div doesn't have enough space to fit in one line

Comment: Morpheus, the problem he's trying to solve is that he believes the overflow: hidden should just truncate it. He understands that it won't fit on one line at that width.

Comment: That is the expected behavior of `inline-block` if there's not space for the second element it wraps. The only alternatives are `white-space: nowrap` or to put those two divs in a wide enough div to fit them all (i.e. wrap a div with width 9999px around them).

Comment: @Greg Pettit Yes, that was my thinking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `white-space: nowrap` on the container: https://jsfiddle.net/1631rrpn/3/

```
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#first {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  display: inline-block;
}

#second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
```